# Java getHours(), getMinutes() and getSeconds()

Tags: java, date, hour, seconds, minute

As I know `getHours()`, `getMinutes()` and `getSeconds()` are all deprecated in Java and they are replaced with `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`, `Calendar.MINUTE`, `Calendar.SECOND`.

These will in fact return the hour, minute and second for that particular moment. However, I would want to retrieved the hours and minutes from a Date variable. For instance,

say the time retrieved from database is

```
time = Thu Jan 01 09:12:18 CET 1970;

int hours = time.getHours();
int minutes = time.getMinutes();
int seconds = time.getSeconds();
```

By retrieving the hours, minutes, and seconds, I get

```
hours = 9
minutes = 12
seconds = 18
```

So, how do I use Calendar for this function? Although the `getHours()` has been deprecated but it still worked. I would still like to know if there is an alternative to this.

Comment: In modern Java, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as `Calendar` have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 184):

Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourdate);
int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Edit:

```
hours, minutes, seconds
```

above will be the hours, minutes and seconds after converting `yourdate` to System Timezone!

Comment: Also, if you need to set timezone, add 

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    // ... init calendar
    calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
<code>

Answer (score 35):

Java 8

```
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getHour());       // 7
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getMinute());     // 45
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().getSecond());     // 32
```

Calendar

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));  // 7 
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));       // 45
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));       // 32
```

Joda Time

```
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getHourOfDay());      // 7
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getMinuteOfHour());   // 45
    System.out.println(new DateTime().getSecondOfMinute()); // 32
```

### Formatted

Java 8

```
    // 07:48:55.056
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
    // 7:48:55
    System.out.println(LocalTime.now().getHour() + ":" + LocalTime.now().getMinute() + ":" + LocalTime.now().getSecond());

    // 07:48:55
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

    // 074855
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

    // 07:48:55 
    System.out.println(new Date().toString().substring(11, 20));
```

Comment: V useful rundown: those are probably the most common sets of date/time systems today.

Comment: But it displayed, hours and minutes in single digit. Is it possible show two digit

Comment: I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is optimal. That class cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Use `ZonedDateTime.now` instead.

Answer (score 9):

For a time difference, note that the calendar starts at 01.01.1970, 01:00, not at 00:00. If you're using java.util.Date and java.text.SimpleDateFormat, you will have to compensate for 1 hour:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + (1*3600 + 23*60 + 45) * 1000 + 678; // 1 h 23 min 45.678 s
Date timeDiff = new Date(end - start - 3600000); // compensate for 1h in millis
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println("Duration: " + timeFormat.format(timeDiff));
```

This will print:

Duration: 1:23:45.678

Comment: wow. just *how* impossible can date manipulation be made in java.

Comment: This is nonsense, and it tries to answer a different question from the one asked. Also for a time difference, since Java 8 you should use the `Duration` class. Except for method names being a bit funny, it behaves nicely and the way you would expect. Neither `Date` nor `SimpleDateFormat` were ever designed to work for a time difference. They also had severe design problems and have been outdated the last 10 years. So don’t use them. Ever.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
ZonedDateTime.now().getHour()
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

> all deprecated in Java and they are replaced with Calendar.

**Update:** Now the `Calendar` class has been supplanted by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class in the *java.time* classes. The modern *java.time* classes have supplanted the terribly flawed legacy classes such as `Calendar` as of JSR 310.

Use `ZonedDateTime` to represent a moment as seen through the clock and calendar used by the people of a particular time zone. Specify the time zone as a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone.
```

If handed a `Calendar` object, cast to its likely subclass [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), then convert from legacy class to modern class.

```
GregorianCalendar gregCal = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalendar ;  // Test with `instanceof` if not certain. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = gregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

You asked:

> getHours(), getMinutes() and getSeconds()

The [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class has equivalent methods.

```
int hour = zdt.getHour() ;
int minute = zdt.getMinute() ;
int second = zdt.getSecond() ;
int nano = zdt.getNano() ;  // The fraction of a second, as a count of nanoseconds ( zero to a billion ).
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to use this answer for your production code. The legacy `java.util` date-time API was flawed and error-prone.