# Using Java, how can i see if the current time is between 10 and 15 minutes after the hour?

Tags: java, time

I need to determine if the current time is between 10 and 15 minutes after the hour. So e.g.:

- if the current time is 9:22 or 14:41, the answer is false
- if the current time is 1:12 or 18:14, the answer is true

I can't find an example of this anywhere.  Does anyone have a general solution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907170/java-getminutes-and-gethours. The question might be different from yours, but you can find your answer there.

Comment: OK - so you're saying use JodaTime TimeOfDay.MINUTE_OF_HOUR. Great.

Comment: BTW, no idea why I have -3 on this?!

Comment: You now have -4 on this as you clearly didn't do the expected minimal amount of research - simply searching for some combination of the words "java time minute" should give you a few thousand links which help solve the problem on your own. E.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150155/java-gethours-getminutes-and-getseconds) is the third result for the exact query `java time minute`.

Comment: @Mark There are even other nice examples in that thread, for example the one from James. It's the same as the answer below.

Comment: Did you see where i said "i can't find this"?!  I DID search, but didn't find this exact situation/solution.  harsh

Comment: I DID look. The fact that I couldn't find an answer is no reason to vote down !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method should resolve your problem

```
public boolean isInRange() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    return minute >= 10 && minute < 15;
}
```

It simple recoveries the minute from the current time and verifies if it is between 10 and 15

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int min = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
return min >= 10 && min < 15;
```

Comment: This doesn't verifies if the minute is > 10

Comment: fixed - now I check - thanks

Comment: Also, it should be lesser than 15, otherwise 10:15:59 will be inside your range

Answer (score 0):

```
int minutes = new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
if (minutes >= 10 && minutes <= 15) {
    System.out.println("The time is between 10 and 15 minutes after the current hour.");
}
```