# How to replace old getCurrentHour() with new getHour()?

Tags: android

I have these code and work well  to show time from timePicker. the code use getCurrentHour and  getCurrentMinute.

```
public void setTime(View view) {
    int hour = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
    int min = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();
    showTime(hour, min);
}

public void showTime(int hour, int min) {
    if (hour == 0) {
        hour += 12;
        format = "AM";
    }
    else if (hour == 12) {
        format = "PM";
    } else if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        format = "PM";
    } else {
        format = "AM";
    }
    time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(" : ").append(min)
            .append(" ").append(format));
}
```

The android Studio tell me to use new getHour() and getMinute() instead.

when I use them in the code above the app stop and crash. why and how to use them correctly.

This is the error in logcat:
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getHour()I in class Landroid/widget/TimePicker; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.widget.TimePicker' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)

Comment: You have to look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8150155/2715073)

Comment: The function is getHour() not getHours() and getMinute() not getMinutes() if you are using android.widget.TimePicker

Comment: Yes: The new functions are getHour() and getMinute()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check SDK version using `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`:

```
int hour = 0;
int min = 0;

int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentApiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
    hour = timePicker1.getHour();
    min = timePicker1.getMinute();
} else {
    hour = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
    min = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works well with new time functions getMinute() and getHour() in emulator, So the problem probably cause because of API used. These tow functions require API 23.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is all you need don't follow other guides. Do the check and then just use `timePicker.getCurrentHour` and `timePicker.getCurrentHour` this is for below `API 23`. For 23 and above use `timePicker.getHour` and `timePicker.getMinute` for minutes.