# How to display either of the two values as a TextView, based on the time and date on the user's device?

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm creating an app for a coffee shop which should display information about whether it is closed or open in a given time. The app should display either "OPEN" or "CLOSED" as a `TextView` based on the time on user's device.

The coffee shop is open from 10:00:00 at morning and closed at 24:00:00 at night. Also, it is open from WED-SUN (MON and TUE closed).

For that, I created a `TextView` layout in XML with empty text field:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_text_view"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In java file I created a `TextView` element and referred to the `TextView` layout in the `XML` file:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
```

I also fetched date and time from user's device by using:

```
String currentDateTimeString = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

From here I don't know how to do the final task of displaying either "OPEN" or "CLOSED" in the `TextView` layout based on date,time and day on the user's device. What I could do is only display the current date and time in the `TextView` layout by using the code:

```
textView.setText(currentDateTimeString);
```

Note : If you share any code, kindly add comments describing each line of code as I'm a beginner level programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 8 introduces the `java.time.*` package which should be prefered! You can find more information in [Java SE 8 Date and Time](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

You should consider using `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

The following function gives a simple example to decide if your shop is open:

```java
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

boolean isOpen() {
   LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

   // now.getHour/( returns the hour-of-day, from 0 to 23
   // so every hour that is greater equals 10 means open
   boolean isOpenByTime = now.getHour() >= 10;

   DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = now.getDayOfWeek();
   boolean isOpenByWeekDay = dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.MONDAY && dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;

   return isOpenByTime && isOpenByWeekDay;
}
```

You can then use `isOpen()` like:

```java
if(isOpen()) { textView.setText("OPEN"); } else { textView.setText("CLOSED"); }
```

**Documentation**

- [StackOverflow: Java: getMinutes and getHours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907170/java-getminutes-and-gethours)

Comment: Pasting your code is throwing me a few errors even after doing necessary imports. Do I need to  do anything with my Java installation , as you talked about some newer Java version ? I'm using Android Studio for linux with JDK embedded.

Comment: You need to have Java 8

Comment: Hi, your code has one issue. In the fifth and sixth line, .hour and .dayOfWeek shows error. It says cannot resolve symbol 'hour', 'dayOfWeek', etc......... Can you please solve this issue?

Comment: I appologize, I originally wrote this in Kotlin, so they were issues with calling the functions. I fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an if...else condition to set that TextView.

This is the example I think would help.

```
if((currentTime > openTime) && (currentTime < closeTime)) {     
   if((currentDay != dayMonday) && (currentDay != dayTuesday)) {
      textView.setText("OPEN");
   }
} else {
   textView.setText("CLOSED");
}
```

The first IF statement (if((currentTime > openTime) && (currentTime < closeTime))) to make sure the statement only returns TRUE if the currentTime variable is between 1000hrs to 2400hrs.

The second IF statement (if((currentDay != dayMonday) && (currentDay != dayTuesday))) is to make sure it return TRUE only if the currentDay is NOT MONDAY or TUESDAY.

And, your currentDateTimeString gives Date & the current Time together. So you have to parse it according to currentDay and currentTime or find suitable constants from [Calendar class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).

Good luck. Hope it helps

Comment: Where and how do I specify the value for openTime, closeTime and weekdays?

Comment: @ChristianB suggestion to use JAVA SE *8 Date and TIME is actually good too, instead of Calendar class. It comes with specified member variables

Answer (score 0):

I wrote your solution in JAVA Compiler, but logic will still work for android
Just Implement the functions **checkIfClosed(), getDay() and currentTime()**.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class checkIfclosed {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            System.out.println(checkIfClosed());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String checkIfClosed() throws ParseException {
        String out = "";
        if(!(getDay().equals("MONDAY") || getDay().equals("TUESDAY"))){

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            if(dateFormat.parse(currentTime()).after(dateFormat.parse("10:00:00")) 
            && dateFormat.parse(currentTime()).before(dateFormat.parse("24:00:00"))){
                out = "OPEN";
            }
            else{
                out = "CLOSED";
            }
        }
        else{
            out = "CLOSED";
        }

        return out;
    }


    private static String getDay(){
        String ox = "";
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.from(localDate);
        ox = dayOfWeek.name();
        return ox;
    }

    private static String currentTime(){
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        return dtf.format(now);
    }
    
}
```

> Android Code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            Log.v("isClosed", checkIfClosed());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static String checkIfClosed() throws ParseException {
        String out = "";
        if(!(getDay().equals("MONDAY") || getDay().equals("TUESDAY"))){

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            if(dateFormat.parse(currentTime()).after(dateFormat.parse("10:00:00"))
                    && dateFormat.parse(currentTime()).before(dateFormat.parse("24:00:00"))){
                out = "OPEN";
            }
            else{
                out = "CLOSED";
            }
        }
        else{
            out = "CLOSED";
        }

        return out;
    }


    private static String getDay(){
        String ox = "";
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.from(localDate);
        ox = dayOfWeek.name();
        return ox;
    }

    private static String currentTime(){
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        return dtf.format(now);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make it android studio specific please?

Comment: it will work on any device you just have to implement the methods in android studio.

Comment: hey check out I made an android specific implementation as you requested, the output in logcat is V/isClosed: OPEN

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. The code is now error free. But the job is still not done. Can you please tell me how do I now display the status (either "OPEN" or "CLOSED") in a textview XML element.

Comment: Just use textView.setText(checkIfClosed());