# Decrement a date in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date, utilities

I want to get the previous day (24 hours) from the current time.

e.g if current time is `Date currentTime = new Date();`

> 2011-04-25 12:15:31:562 GMT

How to determine time i.e

> 2011-04-24 12:15:31:562 GMT

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do that using [Calendar class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime ( date ); // convert your date to Calendar object
int daysToDecrement = -1;
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToDecrement);
date = cal.getTime(); // again get back your date object
```

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest you use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to start with, which is a *much* nicer API. Then you can use:

```
DateTime yesterday = new DateTime().minusDays(1);
```

Note that "this time yesterday" isn't always 24 hours ago though... you need to think about time zones etc. You may want to use `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: A quick download new link for Joda-Time external JAR library: [URL](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases)

Answer (score 2):

please checkout this here:
[Java Date vs Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404210/java-date-vs-calendar)

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date); //not sure if date.getTime() is needed here
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
Date newDate = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

24 hours and 1 day are not the same thing. But you do both using Calendar:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date());
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
Date d = c.getTime();
```

If you are going back 24 hours, you would use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("Now:       " + now);

        Instant yesterday = now.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("Yesterday: " + yesterday);
    }
}
```

**Output of a sample run:**

```
Now:       2021-07-16T20:40:24.402592Z
Yesterday: 2021-07-15T20:40:24.402592Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ot0kWB)

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>