# Is there (still) any good reason to use java Date/Time Calender API?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, deprecated, jodatime

I am tired of using them, Every time I think now I know these APIs I find some thing contradicting, contriving !

I have read lot of evil about them, and there are many reasons scattered across the SO forum (see linked section)

If it doesn't have any good reasons to be survived [IMO there isn't any], why can't java community mark/spread them as deprecated?

Can we please list all the evils they have caused so far to the people so that newbies can read understand and go for alternate better APIs like [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267228/good-reason-to-use-java-util-date-in-an-api

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: http://www.wolkje.net/2010/01/06/java-date-and-time-api-and-jsr-310/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404210/java-date-vs-calendar

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/related.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "no" but answers need more characters.

No; JodaTime is significantly better. In theory, [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) will bring about the deprecation that should have come some time ago. We shall see.

Comment: I will be waiting for it ... Till then I would use http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

May be Java 8 will have JodaTime inspired Date Time API but right now I suggest the Joda time.

Comment: Yep, Joda Time is much better