# How do you format a timestamp string to a Date object in Java?

Tags: java, spring, timestamp

I'm creating a web service in Java using a Spring framework. It takes in an HTTP request with parameters 'payer', 'points', and 'timestamp'.

I need to store the data objects in a list and sort the list by timestamp, so I'm trying to convert the timestamp string to a Date object. Here's my current code:

```
String[] payers; // stores all payers
int totalPayers = 0; // number of payers in 'payers'

@GetMapping("/transaction")
    public void addTrans(@RequestParam(value="payer") String payer, @RequestParam(value="points") int points, @RequestParam(value="timestamp") String time) throws Exception{

        Date timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(time);
        
        Transaction newTrans = new Transaction(timestamp, payer, points);
        totalTrans++;

        // if the payer is new, add them to the payers list
        boolean newPayer = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < totalPayers; i++){
            if (payer == payers[i]){
                newPayer = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(newPayer){
            payers[totalPayers++] = payer;
        }

        transactions.add(newTrans); // add the new transaction to the list
        totalPoints += newTrans.getPoints();

        Collections.sort(transactions); // sort the list by timestamp

        return;
    }
```

When I run it, I'm getting the error:

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-11-02T14:00:00Z"

Does anyone know of something I may be missing? Is there an easier way to convert the string?

Comment: can you share the request url  with dummy values ? I think the input format is not as expected

Comment: Try `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

Comment: Side note: It is best to [avoid `Date` wherever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347481/12567365). Use classes from `java.time` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat parsing date with 'Z' literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580925/simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-z-literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee single quotes around the `Z` too.

```
Date timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(time);
```

The Z is not part of the pattern the function is supposed to recognize.

Comment: This is so very wrong. ***Never* put quote marks around the Z.** The Z provides vital crucial information: the offset from UTC. By quoting, you are telling the formatter to ignore the Z altogether, thereby discarding the vital info. Please delete this Answer before this disinformation spreads.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

## *java.time*

Your input format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard used by default in the *java.time* classes. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

The `T` separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion. The `Z` on the end tells you the date and time is a moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu” per aviation and military conventions.

Parsing text in standard ISO 8601 format:

```
String input = "2022-01-23T12:34:56Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.now( input ) ;
```

Generating text in standard ISO 8601 format:

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or above, it is recommended to use `java.time` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) instead of `java.util.Date`.

But if you really want to use Date, the below snippet should help you resolve the error and parse the string. Be wary of the zone calculation.

```
Date timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX").parse(time);
```

If you decide to switch to `java.time`, the below snippet would help

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse(time) ;
Date date = java.util.Date.from(instant);
```