# primefaces calendar: wrong date entry

Tags: java, netbeans, primefaces

Using jsf 2.2.0.

For all the date, it seems to remove one day. When I click on 8 nov, it displays 11/08/2011.
But then it stores Nov 7, 2011 in my Date field in my managed bean.

I live in singapore, wondering if it's an issue with the timezone.

Comment: Could be. If not, it can be a problem of Primefaces. It is quite buggy... Anyway, don't use `Date`-s, use `Calendar`-s instead.

Comment: A Date field can't even store a specific date. All it stores is an integer. There are different ways of transating that integer to a date, which is where your problem is coming from.

Comment: @zeller I am interested in your recommendation not to use java.util.Date. Why is this?

Comment: @7SpecialGems: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404210/java-date-vs-calendar

Answer (score 25):

try adding this to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Its definitely a timezone issue. You may (should be) running your server in UTC. Primefaces will regionalize your date and convert it to the user time. You can, and probably should, run your server with 
"-Duser.timezone=UTC". The context param should fix it.

Comment: Confirmed, timezone issue. The context param fixed it (JSF 2.2.5, PrimeFaces 4.0).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using primefaces 5, in your scheduler :

```
<p:schedule ...ignoreTimezone="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the argument `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to the startup parameters fixed problem for me.

To summarize:
p:schedule work only well when following parameters are sets:

`-Duser.timezone=UTC`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just added the following parameter in web.xml and the issue is fixed.  I didn't include any command like -Duser.timezone=UTC while starting the server, still its fixed the issue.

javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE
    true

Regards
Khaleel

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Wildfly 8 and PF 5.0.RC1 and the only thing that did the trick for me was setting the Timezone of the calendar to nothing...

```
<p:calendar timeZone = "" />
```

Don't know if this is a proper solution, seems more like a workaround, but it worked fine locally and deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you didn't insert the hours. For example in this case

```
<p:calendar id="dateFromCalendar"
    value="#{platform.frameBean.dateFrom}" showOn="button"
    pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" timeZone="Europe/Warsaw">
</p:calendar>
```

the hour will come as 00:00 of the actual day. And because the timezone (-02:00), the hour will appear as 22:00 of the day before the actual day. The correct thing to do is

```
<p:calendar id="dateFromCalendar"
    value="#{platform.frameBean.dateFrom}" showOn="button"
    pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" timeZone="Europe/Warsaw">
</p:calendar>
```

The hour will appear, so the timezone will make the correct calculations

Answer (score 0):

In your calendar component, add a converter and indicate your timezone e.g

```
<p:calendar id="date">
  <f:convertDateTime timeZone="Asia/Singapore"></f:convertDateTime>
</p:calendar
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to set the `timezone` and `locate` attribute?
Otherwise, you can create a converter object that converts the date.
This is a tutorial to create a custom converter: http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/customconverter.shtml