# jsf datetimeconverter showing date one day before

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces

jsf 2 glassfish 4 primefaces 5.1

i am using the f:convertDateTime to convert the way date is shown but its showing the wrong date.
when i normally show the date it shows 
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 AST 2011

which is correct but its not what i want to show

so i am using `<f:convertDateTime dateStyle="short"></f:convertDateTime>` but instead of showing 
01/01/11
its giving me 
31/12/10

i tried using `<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>` but that also gives me 
12/31/2010
instead of 
01/01/2011

```
<p:column headerText="Installation Date"
    filterBy="#{w.installationDate}"
          filterMatchMode="contains"
          sortBy="#{w.installationDate}">
        <h:outputText value="#{w.installationDate}" >
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
```

Comment: I think you that is a problem with the timezone. Add the timezone to your output to see which timezone is used by the converter.

Comment: @jens thanks, showing the timezone it showed GMT, but its weird i tried using <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" timezone="AST"></f:convertDateTime> earlier didnt work, displaying the timezone after your suggestion showed AST was being set to ASKT. dunno why. set it manually to "Asia/Riyadh" and it worked

Comment: @yahh, how about doing the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029448/617373

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this to your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```