# how to get dateTime based on hour and minute

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar

I have hour and minute in edittext.(say for example 10:50)

how to get today's DateTime(like yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) based on above edit text value 10:50

UPDATE:
this worked for me:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
```

thank you all

Comment: Do I get that correctly? The user enters a time of day, say 10:50 — using a 24 hour clock? From that you need to get today’s date at the time entered, for example 2017-09-06 10:50:00 — right?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: take a look at this [other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42498249/3732003) about why one should prefer using the Java 8 `java.time` classes over `Calendar` or `Date`

In your instance, in order to parse an input in the form "HH:mm", you can create a `DateTimeFormatter` and use the static method `LocalTime.parse(inputString, dateTimeFormatter)` to get a [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) object

For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeInputString, formatter);
```

Take a look at the [Java documentation for DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more information on the patterns for years, days, or whatever.

If you're wanting to get both the date and time from a string such as "10:50", you won't be able to using the `LocalDateTime.parse` method because it can't obtain the date from an "HH:mm" string. So the way around this is to create the time off of `LocalTime.parse` as shown above, and then get the current date using the static method `LocalDate.now();` And then combine those two results into a `LocalDateTime` object using it's static factory method `LocalDateTime.of(date, time)`

For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeInputString, formatter);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, time);
```

Comment: Well explained answer, thank you. I would prefer to pass a time zone to `LocalDate.now()`, using the overloaded version that accepts a `ZoneId`, to make it explicit that we are asking for today’s date on a specific spot on earth. One may use for example `ZoneId.of("Africa/Banjul")` (substituting the relevant region and city) or `ZoneId.systemDefault()` (to use the device’s time zone setting).

Comment: You can use the Java 8 `java.time` classes with Android Java 7. It’s all explained very nicely in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 1):

```
   Calendar cal = new Calendar.getInstance();// today's date 
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
 cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
 cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime()); //see the result
```

now , it's up to you to put them directly in cal.set with variables (not manually writing 10 ,50 , it's up to your creativity )

And this answer is with Calendar because you tagged Calendar in your question , you can also use something else than Calender

Comment: the difficulty was how to assign hour and min to cal.set. 10 and 50 are just example, those edittext values are dynamic

Comment: you said edittext, so he will enter 10 in the first edittext , then 50 in the second ! so those 2 edittext can be related to variables, then you use the variables in the set . 
the best way is to use an existing time api, so he will choose the hour and the minutes (so he can't  for exemple enter: 23 hour, 70 minutes) then you catch them with the getters of the clock .

Comment: yes good explaination. I had to change the design. When on clicking the edittext with HH:mm value, i had to open TimePicketDialog and select the appropriate time. on selecting time from TimePicker it give the dateTime of the selected value, so it helped

Answer (score 0):

you just need use this function.

```
// hourMintText = "hh:mm"
private String getTodayAsFormat(String hourMintText){
    String[] hourMinAsArray = hourMintText.split(":");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hourMinAsArray[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(hourMinAsArray[1]));
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

    return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss aa", Locale.getDefault())
                        .format(new Date());
```

Comment: How does 10:50 (or whatever the user entered) come into that?