# JPA 2.0 and Oracle with TemporalType.TIME

Tags: oracle, datetime, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm Using Oracle 11g and JPA 2.0 (hibernate in JBoss 6.0.0).
I need to represent a time range in an entity, so I defined those fields:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date startTime;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date endTime;
```

The generated tables use two DATE fields, and this is ok since Oracle doesn't have a type representing just the time part.

When loading the entity from db, just the time part is loaded (the field contains a java.sql.Time).
I've seen instead that if I set a complete date+time in the fields, the date part will be persisted to the db.

Is there a way to ensure that the date part will not be persisted to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write setter methods which remove the date component. Quick and dirty example:

```
public void setStartTime(Date startTime)
{
    this.startTime = new Time(startTime.getTime() % 86400000L);
}
```

Though you'd be better off using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to do your date/time calculations (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/)). I didn't test this to make sure it's correct, but it should show you the basic idea:

```
public void setStartTime(Date startTime)
{
    this.startTime = new Time(LocalTime.fromDateFields(startTime).millisOfDay().get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using your solution (but used Calendar to strip the date part to avoid the dependency on Joda Time, at the moment). I'm wondering if there is a way to tell JPA to take care of this part or similar.