# Differences between java.util.Date and Joda Time APIs

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use Java date and time classes or go with a 3rd party library like Joda Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda)

I could use some guidance about when it's worth using Joda Time rather than the basic java.util.Date class. What are the benefits? Does Joda Time let you do anything you can't do with the Date class, or is it just easier to work with or what?

Also, I've seen conflicting info about whether Joda Time is part of the standard API. Is it standard or not?

Comment: Use Joda Time, it's a much better API.

Comment: Read the documentation of **Jodatime** api.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jodatime/index.html#N100BA  But seriously, use JODA; try not to even consider `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @andyczerwonka I already edited my question.Is it OK? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes it is OK ... whatever that means.  But if you are asking for permission, you are asking the wrong people.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Java's standard date and time classes (mainly `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`) have limited functionality and have a number of design problems. The fact that many of the constructors and methods of `java.util.Date` are deprecated is one indication of this.

Joda Time has a much better thought out API than what's available in Java's standard library. There are classes for timestamps with or without a timezone, classes for holding only a date (year, month, day) or only a time of day, classes for periods, durations and intervals, it supports the ISO 8601 format (which is the standard format in XML documents) and much more.

I'd use Joda Time as my standard date and time library in any project - there really is no reason to use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

Note that in a future release of Java, a new date and time API will most likely be included that's going to look a lot like what's currently available in Joda Time; see [Project ThreeTen](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen).

Also see [Why Joda Time?](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) on the home page of the Joda Time project.

> Also, I've seen conflicting info about whether Joda Time is part of the standard API. Is it standard or not?

No, it isn't part of the [standard API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

**Update (copied from the comments):**

Java 8 is out now, and it has a new date and time API which is similar to Joda Time (see the package java.time). If you're using Java 8, then please use the new date & time API.

Comment: Update: Java 8 is out now, and it has a new date and time API which is similar to Joda Time (see the package `java.time`). If you're using Java 8, then please use the new date & time API.

Comment: Currently I use Java 7 on my project with Joda Time API. But I will try to test Java 8's new date and time API.Anyway Thanks man

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye There's now also a [backport of the Java 8 date and time API](http://www.threeten.org/) available - a separate library that you can use with Java 7, which will give you the new Java 8 date and time API (with minor differences).