# Calculating time diffrence

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to calculate time diffrence between dates:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String start = "2013-03-10 10:28:47.000000";
    String end = "2013-04-07 09:54:08.054577";

    CalculateDuration calc = new CalculateDuration();
    calc.calculateDiffrenceInMinutes(start,end);
}
public int calculateDiffrenceInMinutes(String start_time, String end_time)
{

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {
        d1 = format.parse(start_time);
        d2 = format.parse(end_time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

    // Get msec from each, and subtract.
    int diff = (int) d2.getTime() - (int)d1.getTime();
    int diffSeconds = (int) (diff / 1000);         
    int diffMinutes = (int) (diff / (60 * 1000));         
    int diffHours = (int) (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));                      

    return diffMinutes;
}
```

For some reason i cant understand the example i show give a negetive output even though the end date is after the start date.

Any ideas?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, it's generally better to make functions take the actual parameters they're interested in; your method ought to take `Date`s, not `String`s. This makes it easier to test (maybe your conversion wasn't working properly) and more flexible to use.

Comment: @chrylis And also, because it might lead to situations later on, where someone converts his `Date` instances to `String` so he can call this method (which then converts them back to `Date`). Which is completeley needless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing

```
int diff = (int) d2.getTime() - (int)d1.getTime();
```

to

```
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
```

Explicit typecasting from `long` to `int` will cause precision loss and may result in a negative value on subtraction.

```
long a = 90000000000000L;
long b = 10000001000000L;

a>b
(int)a-(int)b => negative value
```

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed out about precision loss, you can read the details in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#189955).

```
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;  
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours   = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 60;
```

Java's date-time API has some design issues. Calendar is not thread safe. You may want to look at [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). This would make it as simple as-

```
Seconds.between(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: How is Java's Calendar "very much buggy"?  Can you point out some unresolved bugs?  That is a bold statement to put in an answer.

Comment: @VGR I don't want to write a long message. So here are some answers might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032051/differences-between-java-util-date-and-joda-time-apis

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131324/is-java-util-calendar-thread-safe-or-not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda

Answer (score 2):

`Date#getTime()` returns a `long` and that has a reason. Because quite a few milliseconds have passed since *January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT*. An `int` can't hold that huge number (and overflows, which explains why you might get negative numbers (depending on the two dates)). So you should use `long` to do the calculations.

I would change your code like this:

```
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / (          1000);         
long diffMinutes = diff / (     60 * 1000);         
long diffHours   = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Of course, you also need to change the return type of your `calculateDiffrenceInMinutes` method to `long`.

Note: In your example, you could also leave `diffSeconds`, `diffMinutes` and `diffHours` as `int`. But I wouldn't recommend that, as this would be a solution that fails if the dates are too far apart.