# Change the first week of a year

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

Using Java's Calendar or something else, let's say I set the date to 2012-10-26. I want this date to be the first day of a year. Is it possible to get the week number of a specific date -let's say it's 2012-12-10- assuming that the first week of the year starts from 2012-10-26?

I know my question sounds a little weird, but I could use any useful input.

Thanks.

**--Details**

I have a database table called *WeeklySchedule*. In this table I have columns starting from *Week1* to *Week52*, and every column have some data about the days of that week. Unfortunately, *Week1* is not really the first week of the year. I need to do my calculations assuming that *Week1* starts from *2012-08-26*.

Comment: Tried anything? At least gone through the documentation of `Calendar`>

Comment: @Nambari I added some details about my problem. Unfortunately, I don't have any working code right now, because I don't know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: @RohitJain yes I tried to manually set the Calendar date to 2012-08-26, and then set the WEEK_OF_YEAR to 1; but when I change the WEEK_OF_YEAR, the date changes automatically. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using the Calendar API:

```
private static final Calendar START_CAL = createAugust26th2012Cal();

public int getWeekNumber(Calendar someCal) {
    int theWeek = someCal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int weekCount = 0;
    while (theWeek != START_CAL.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)) {
        someCal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
        theWeek = someCal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        weekCount++;
    }
    return weekCount;
}
```

---

Or you could get the diff (in millis) between two calendars and divide the result by the number of millis in a week:

If you use this approach, don't forget to take TimeZones and Daylight Saving Time into account.

I can't remember *exactly* what the code looks like to compensate for DST, but I think it's something like this:
*(I can't quite remember if you add the offset to or subtract the offset from the two operands)*

```
private static final long ONE_WEEK_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

public int getWeeksBetween(Calendar calOne, Calendar calTwo) {
    long millisOne = calOne.getTime().getTime();
    long millisTwo = calTwo.getTime().getTime();
    long offsetOne = calOne.getTimeZone().getOffset(millisOne);
    long offsetTwo = calTwo.getTimeZone().getOffset(millisTwo);
    long diff = (millisTwo - offsetTwo) - (millisOne + offsetOne );
    return diff / ONE_WEEK_MILLIS;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm already using this approach, but I think it's not the best approach. There should be another dynamic way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect this kind of code to exist in a library.  It takes very little work to implement yourself.  The other approach I'd suggest is to subract the time between two dates in milliseconds and divide by the number of millis in a week (then round the result).  Don't forget to take into account TimeZones if you do it this way!

Comment: @jahroy I have just realized something about the first code piece that you gave: assuming that the start date is "08-26-2012" and the someCal date is "2013-03-16", the weekCount will be 28, and the DAY_OF_WEEK will be 7 (saturday). If we keep the start date same, and change someCal to "2013-03-17", the weekCount will stay the same, but the DAY_OF_WEEK will be 1 (sunday). In that case, weekCount should be 29. Is that some kind of Calendar bug, or a logic error in your code?

Comment: my code is untested... i would hope the calendar code is bug free!

Comment: @alicozgo - now that i think about it, that code should use `Calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1)` in stead of roll. that should fix it. (i'm at a football game now).

Comment: looks like it's working now. thank you so much for your valuable time and idea.

Comment: @alicozgo - Now that I think about it, this answer is still incorrect.  What if _someDate_ is in September 2013?  It won't work.  You might be trying to achieve something that is not technically possible to define.  That being said, I'm really not sure because I don't know your exact requirements.  That being said, if _someDate_ will always be _within a year_ of the start date, this code should be fine.

Comment: @jahroy actually, these weeks represent the academic calendar of some college (08-26-2012 to 05-15-2013). so, someDate will always be within a year of the start date, but it might not be the same year. for example startDate=2012-12-28 and someDate=2013-02-09 is one of the possible cases. I'm still testing this code, so far it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever seen a built-in function for this, only calls like [`Calendar.get(WEEK_OF_YEAR)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR) or [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)'s [`LocalDate.getWeekOfWeekyear()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#getWeekOfWeekyear()). `java.util.Calendar` (and `Date`) is often regarded as a bad library, compared to a library like Joda Time. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda) has a good list of pros and cons.

Note that if your database table applies to year after year repeats across a year, you may run into trouble. Some years ([71 years per 400, or about 1 every 5.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)) have 53 weeks.

Given the above, you may want to settle for an approximation, such as counting the number of [days between the two dates](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html) divided by 7 (all mod 52), which will slip by a small amount each year, or calculating `(weekOfYear(date) - weekOfYear(startDate)) % 52`, which may repeat a week around the beginning of the calendar year.