# Differences between Java 8 Date Time API (java.time) and Joda-Time

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime, java-time

I know there are questions relating to [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and Joda-Time. But after some digging, I couldn't find a thread about the differences between the [java.time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (new in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29), defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)) and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

I have heard that Java 8’s java.time API is much cleaner and can do much more than Joda-Time. But I cannot find examples comparing the two.

- What can java.time do that Joda-Time cannot?
- What can java.time do better than Joda-Time?
- Is the performance better with java.time?

Comment: It is not, that is pertaining to Java 7, not Java 8. The answer to that question was edited for Java 8 with very very little detail. My question specifically is asking about Java 8's new DateTime API, not Java 7's java.util.Date. I'm just looking for an answer that compares Java 8 to JodaTime.

Comment: perhaps [this Oracle document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) can help you.

Comment: If you have Java 7, use the additional library, if you have Java 8, use the built in library.  Since both libraries are basically designed by the same person, I am not sure what major differences you are expecting.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Joda-Time and the Java 8 date and time API are actually quite different.

Comment: You can also read [this blog post](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html) from Stephen Colbourne - the primary author of both projects.

Answer (score 470, accepted):

**Common features**

a) Both libraries use immutable types. Joda-Time also offers additional mutable types like `MutableDateTime`.

b) Furthermore: Both libraries are inspired by the design study ["TimeAndMoney" from Eric Evans](http://timeandmoney.sourceforge.net/) or ideas from [Martin Fowler about domain driven style](http://martinfowler.com/tags/domain%20driven%20design.html) so they strive more or less for a [fluent programming style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (although not always perfect ;-)).

c) With both libraries we get a real calendar date type (called `LocalDate`), a real wall time type (called `LocalTime`) and the composition (called `LocalDateTime`). That is a very big win compared with old `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`.

d) Both libraries use a method-centric approach meaning they encourage the user to use `getDayOfYear()` instead of `get(DAY_OF_YEAR)`. This causes a lot of extra methods compared with `java.util.Calendar` (although latter is not type-safe at all due to excessive use of ints).

**Performance**

See the other answer by @OO7 pointing to the analysis of Mikhail Vorontsov although point 3 (exception catching) is probably obsolete - see [this JDK-bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046707). The different performance (which is in general favour of [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)) is mainly due to the fact that the internal implementation of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) always use a machine-time-like long-primitive (in milliseconds).

**Null**

Joda-Time often use NULL as default for system timezone, default locale, current timestamp etc. while JSR-310 almost always rejects NULL values.

**Precision**

JSR-310 handles [nanosecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) precision while Joda-Time is limited to [millisecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) precision.

**Supported fields:**

An overview about supported fields in Java-8 (JSR-310) is given by some classes in the temporal-package (for example [ChronoField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) and [WeekFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html)) while Joda-Time is rather weak on this area - see [DateTimeFieldType](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeFieldType.html). The biggest lack of Joda-Time is here the absence of localized week-related fields. A common feature of both field implementation design is that both are based on values of type long (no other types, not even enums).

**Enum**

JSR-310 offers [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) like `DayOfWeek` or `Month` while Joda-Time does not offer this because it was mainly developed in years 2002-2004 before [Java 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29).

**Zone API**

a) JSR-310 offers more timezone features than Joda-Time. Latter is not able to yield a programmatical access to the history of timezone offset transitions while JSR-310 is capable to do this.

b) For your information: JSR-310 has moved its internal timezone repository to a new location and a different format. The old library folder lib/zi does not exist any more.

**Adjuster vs. Property**

JSR-310 has introduced the `TemporalAdjuster`-interface as a formalized way to externalize temporal calculations and manipulations, especially for library or framework-writers this is a nice and relative easy way to embed new extensions of JSR-310 (a kind of equivalent to static helper classes for former `java.util.Date`).

For most users however, this feature has very limited value because the burden to write code is still with the user. Built-in solutions based on the new `TemporalAdjuster`-concept are not so many, there is currently only the helper class `TemporalAdjusters` with a limited set of manipulations (and the enums `Month` or other temporal types).

Joda-Time offers a field-package but practice has shown evidence that new field implementations are very hard to code. On the other side Joda-Time offers so-called properties which make some manipulations much easier and more elegant than in JSR-310, for example [property.withMaximumValue()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html#withMaximumValue()).

**Calendar systems**

JSR-310 offers 4 extra calendar systems. The most interesting one is [Umalqura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar#Saudi_Arabia.27s_Umm_al-Qura_calendar) (used in Saudi Arabia). The other 3 are: [Minguo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minguo_calendar) (Taiwan), Japanese (only the modern calendar since 1871!) and [ThaiBuddhist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_calendar) (only correct after 1940).

Joda-Time offers an [Islamic calendar](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html) based on calculatory base - not a sighting-based calendar like Umalqura. Thai-Buddhist is also offered by Joda-Time in a similar form, Minguo and the japanese one not. Otherwise Joda-Time offers coptic and ethiopic calendar, too (but without any support for internationalization).

More interesting for Europeans: Joda-Time also offers a [Gregorian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), [Julian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) and mixed-gregorian-julian calendar. However, the practical value for real historical calculations is limited because important features like different year starts in date history are not supported at all (the same criticism is valid for old `java.util.GregorianCalendar`).

Other calendars like [Hebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) or [Persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars) or [Hindu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_calendar) are completely missing in both libraries.

**Epoch days**

JSR-310 has the class [JulianFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html) while Joda-Time (version 2.0) offers some helper methods in the class [DateTimeUtils](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#fromJulianDay(double)).

**Clocks**

JSR-310 has no interface (a design mistake) but an abstract class `java.time.Clock` which can be used for any clock dependency injection. Joda-Time offers the interface [MillisProvider](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider.html) and some helper methods in [DateTimeUtils](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisProvider(org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider)) instead. So this way Joda-Time is also capable of supporting test-driven models with different clocks (mocking etc.).

**Duration arithmetic**

Both libraries support the calculation of time distances in one or more temporal units. However, when handling single-unit-durations the JSR-310-style is obviously nicer (and long-based instead of using int):

JSR-310 => `long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);`

Joda-Time => `int days = DAYS.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();`

Handling of multiple-unit-durations are also different. Even the calculation results can differ - see this closed [Joda-Time issue](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/132). While JSR-310 use a very simple and limited approach to use just the classes `Period` (duration based on years, months and days) and `Duration` (based on seconds and nanoseconds), Joda-Time uses a more sophisticated way using the class `PeriodType` in order to control in which units a duration (Joda-Time call it "Period") shall be expressed. While the `PeriodType`-API is somehow awkward to use a similar way is not offered by JSR-310 at all. Especially it is not yet possible in JSR-310 to define mixed date and time durations (based on days and hours for example). So be warned if it comes to migration from one library to another. The libraries in discussion are incompatible - despite of partially same class names.

**Intervals**

JSR-310 does not support this feature while Joda-Time has limited support. See also this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150722/is-there-a-class-in-java-time-comparable-to-the-joda-time-interval/22152890#22152890).

**Formatting and Parsing**

Best way to compare both libraries is to view the equal-named classes [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) (JSR-310) and [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) (Joda-Time). The JSR-310-variant is a little bit more powerful (can also handle any kind of `TemporalField` provided the field implementor has managed to code some extension points like [resolve()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html#resolve-java.util.Map-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-)). Most important difference is however - in my opinion:

JSR-310 can much better parse timezone names (format pattern symbol z) while Joda-Time could not do this at all in its earlier versions and now only in a very limited way.

Another advantage of JSR-310 is support for standalone month names which is important in languages like Russian or Polish etc. Joda-Time has [no access to such resources](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/273) - not even on Java-8 platforms.

The pattern syntax in JSR-310 is also more flexible than in Joda-Time, allows for optional sections (using square brackets), is more orientated towards CLDR-standard and offers padding (letter symbol p) and more fields.

Otherwise it should be noted that Joda-Time can format durations using [PeriodFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html). JSR-310 cannot do this.

---

Hope this overview helps. All the gathered information is mainly there due to my efforts and investigations how to design and implement a better date-and-time library (nothing is perfect).

**Update from 2015-06-24:**

Meanwhile I have found the time to write and [publish a tabular overview](http://time4j.net/tutorial/appendix.html) for different time libraries in Java. The tables also contain a comparison between Joda-Time v2.8.1 and Java-8 (JSR-310). It is more detailed than this post.

Comment: This is an outstanding post.  Many thanks to share all of this information.  If given the choice between Joda and JSR-310 (for vanilla use cases only), which would you choose?  I am facing this choice right now.  I am considering JSR-310, only because it is newer and I try to support "moving forward" wherever possible.

Comment: @kevinarpe If I had only the choice between JSR-310 and Joda-Time I would probably prefer JSR-310 because Joda-Time has almost stopped any further development (new big features cannot be expected - just bugfixing and small updates). And the design of JSR-310 is simply more modern (and with better internal quality). By the way and not surprising however, my real decision is rather going to prefer my own library Time4J - see also the link to the tabular overview given at the bottom of my post. It is always good to have alternatives, and it strongly depends on what features you need.

Comment: Isn't Duration Java8's version of an Interval?

Comment: @ChristianHujer No, `java.time.Duration` cannot be queried for its start or end, in contrast to an interval which is anchored on a timeline. This JSR-310-type is just a pair of elapsed seconds and nanoseconds since an unknown start.

Answer (score 47):

**Java 8 Date/Time :**

1. Java 8 classes are built around the human time. It makes them fast for human datetime arithmetics/conversion.
2. Date/time component getters like `getDayOfMonth` have O(1) complexity in Java 8 implementation.
3. Parsing of `OffsetDateTime`/`OffsetTime`/`ZonedDateTime` is very slow in Java 8 ea b121 due to exceptions thrown and caught internally in the JDK.
4. A set of packages: `java.time.*`, `java.time.chrono.*`, `java.time.format.*`, `java.time.temporal.*`, `java.time.zone.*`
5. Instants (timestamps) Date and Time Partial Date and Time Parser and Formatter Time zones Different chronologies (calendars).
6. Existing classes have issues like Date has no support for I18N or L10N. They are mutable!
7. Simpler & more robust.
8. Clocks can be injected.
9. Clocks can be created with various properties - Static clocks, Mocked clocks, Low-precision clocks (whole seconds, whole minutes, etc).
10. Clocks can be created with specific time zones. `Clock.system(Zone.of("America/Los_Angeles"))`.
11. Makes code handling date and time testable.
12. Makes tests independent of timezone.

**Joda-Time :**

1. Joda-Time is using machine time inside. A manual implementation based on int/long values would be much faster.
2. Joda-Time getters require the computer-to-human time calculation on every getter call, which makes Joda-Time a bottleneck in such scenarios.
3. It is composed of immutable classes it handles Instants, Date & Time, Partials, and Durations It is flexible It is well designed.
4. Represents dates as instants. But a date&time may correspond to more than one instant. Overlap hour when daylight savings end. As well as not have any instant that corresponds to it at all. Gap hour when daylight starts. Has to perform complex computations for simple operations.
5. Accepts nulls as valid values on most of its methods. Leads to subtle bugs.

**For more detailed comparision see :-**

[Java 8 Date/Time library performance (as well as Joda-Time 2.3 and j.u.Calendar)](https://web.archive.org/web/20181018123257/http://java-performance.info/jsr-310-java-8-datetime-library-performance-well-joda-time-2-3-j-u-calendar). &
[New Date & Time API in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527468/new-date-time-api-in-java-8)

Comment: When you say "Makes tests independent of timezone." What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Zack: Probably that if you test code, which behave differently depending on the time zone, you may be required to force the test to run with a different default timezone that what is provided by the operating system.

Comment: Hah - I thought you said that joda internally ran on a *time machine* rather than machine time... And I wouldn't be surprised

Comment: @OO7 What do you mean 'human time'?  Time is calculated by machines anyway.

Answer (score 17):

## Joda-Time is now in maintenance-mode

Not a direct answer to the question but the [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is no longer in active development. The team suggests users migrate to the newer *java.time* API. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

From the official [GitHub](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) project page:

> Joda-time is no longer in active development except to keep timezone
>   data up to date. From Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to
>   java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this
>   project. For Android users, java.time is added in API 26+. Projects
>   needing to support lower API levels can use the ThreeTenABP library.

Answer (score 1):

> The project has been led jointly by the author of Joda-Time (Stephen Colebourne) and Oracle, under JSR 310, and will appear in the new Java SE 8 package java.time.

https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html