# remove characters from one point to another

Tags: java, string

I have a string that is time and date.
The string always looks like this (but with real dates ofc.)

> 2015-01-06T06:36:12Z

I want to remove the date (plus the T and Z)
To remove the T and Z I can just use regex to remove every non-numberic character so that's not a problem.

My problem is that I have no idea how to remove from character `0` to character `10` -> `2015-01-06T <- I want this removed.`
I've tried some ways but can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

Comment: I would definitely go the parsing route. That provides validation at the same time, which is useful IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use substring:

```
System.out.println("2015-01-06T06:36:12Z".substring(11,19));
```

Comment: You missed the year, therefore the indices are now wrong.

Comment: Thanks, .subString(11,18) did it :)

Comment: @AddemodC I think it should be .substring(11,19)

Comment: @AddemodC Please use `str.substring(str.indexOf('T') + 1, str.indexOf('Z'));` instead (with `str` being the data string). Fixed values are error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 introduced a variety of date functions and when it comes to parsing an formatting a great article can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html). One class that was introduced was the [DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which has one big upside compared to e.g. `SimpleDateFormatter` - **DateTimeFormatter it is thread-safe**.

So, I would probably not use the `substring`-approach that was mentioned in an answer. Instead I would use the `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the string and then output it in the required format. This also offers some validation that the input format is as expected and that the output format is valid as well.

Example:

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException, ParseException {
    // Setup the input formatter
    final DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    // Parse and validate the date
    final LocalDateTime parsed =
            LocalDateTime.parse("2015-01-06T06:36:12Z", inputFormatter);

    // Setup the output formatter
    final DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    // Format the date to the desired format
    String formatted = outputFormatter.format(parsed);

    // Verify the contents (part of test only)
    Assert.assertEquals("06:36:12", formatted);
}
```

The new date and time features in Java 8 are heavily inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631909/differences-between-java-8-date-time-api-java-time-and-joda-time) is good reading for those who are curious what the differences are.

Comment: Wow this looks really cool and simple! Will keep this in mind! :)
Would +1 but I just registered.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SmpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) ,there are other libraries too to work with time anddate.However if you are having some specific types of strings containing date and time information,then you have to manuaaly parse them from your code.
 [See and example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/converting-string-to-date-using-simpledateformat) and [here](http://java67.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html)

Simple code example to start of with

```
Date date = new Date(); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf; 
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); 
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: Yeah I have a string that is just written like date and time so I can't use DateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

`\T\.\w+_fn\Z` This regular expression give you `06:36:12`. It with remove `T`, `Z` and date part.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove "from character 0 to character 10", then you could simply use the `String` class's `substring(int beginIndex)` function.

```
String date = "2015-01-06T06:36:12Z"
String newString = date.substring(11);
// newString will be "06:36:12Z"
```

You have to pass value 11 to the `substring()` function, because you want the new string to be the given *date*, from 11th character to end of it.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
String input ="2015-01-06T06:36:12Z";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf2.format(sdf.parse(input)));
```