# Spring Boot issues serializing java.time.LocalDateTime with Jackson to return ISO-8601 JSON timestamps?

Tags: serialization, spring-boot, java-8, jackson, java-time

I'm working on converting some models in a spring-boot REST API app to use java 8's `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead of joda's `DateTime`. I want the timestamps returned from API call to adhere to the `ISO_8601` format. Motivation is to be forward compatible with Java 8's time ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24635657/187907)).

The part that's proving difficult is when it comes to serialize an object containing `LocalDateTime` to JSON.

For example, I have the following entity:

```
// ... misc imports

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

@Data 
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", timezone = "UTC")
    private java.time.LocalDateTime createdAt;

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.id = Utils.generateUUID();
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
}
```

I have also set my `application.properties` to turn off the dates as timestamp jackson feature:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
```

My maven deps:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

Finally, I try to retrieve the JSON representation via controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(
        value = "/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
    )
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

When I actually make a call to this endpoint, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.JSR310FormattedSerializerBase.findFormatOverrides(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
```

Alternately I also configured the app's `ObjectMapper` in the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getJacksonObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
            false
        );
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Any leads will be greatly appreciated.

---

### UPDATE:

Turns out it was a version mismatch between Spring Boot's Jackson version and the one I had in my `pom.xml`. As Miloš and Andy proposed, once I've set the correct version and run the app with `spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=true`, the issue was resolved, without needing to configure the `ObjectMapper` or adding annotations on my `LocalDateTime` model fields.

```
    ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `NoSuchMethodError` is because you are mixing versions of Jackson. Spring Boot 1.3.6 uses Jackson 2.6.7 and you are using 2.8.1 of `jackson-datatype-jsr310`.

Spring Boot provides dependency management for Jackson, including `jackson-datatype-jsr310`, so you should remove the version from your pom. If you want to use a different version of Jackson, you should override the `jackson.version` property:

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.8.1</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

This will ensure that all your Jackson dependencies have the same version, thereby avoiding problems with mismatched versions.

You can also, if you wish, remove your Java code that's configuring the `ObjectMapper`. The Java Time module will be automatically registered when it's in the classpath and writing dates as timestamps can be configured in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `ObjectMapper` bean must be marked as `@Primary` in order to be picked up by Spring. Alternatively, you can just create a `JavaTimeModule` bean and it will get picked up by Spring and added to the default object mapper.

You've probably seen it already but [take a look at the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

Comment: Thanks Miloš. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: I just noticed that you're using 1.3.6 of Spring Boot with 2.8 Jackson but I don't think they are compatible. Can you try using Boot 1.4?

Comment: Or just use the same version of jsr310 Jackson that comes with Boot 1.3.6 - it should be 2.6.7 I think

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you mix versions of Jackson. You are using version `1.3.6.RELEASE` of Spring Boot. If you would migrate to Spring Boot version `2.x.x.RELEASE` then you can replace the `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype` dependency by a `spring-boot-starter-json` dependency. In this way you let Spring Boot take care of the correct Jackson version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: migration from spring boot 1.3.6 to 2.x.x can have big implications and is a bad advice.

Comment: unfortunately `spring-boot-starter-json` have a dependency on `spring-web`