# LocalDateTime format in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localdate

Hey I've got the same problem as here: [JSON Java 8 LocalDateTime format in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot) I tried solutionts from there and it does not work. Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

I added

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

to application.property
My model class looks like this:

```
package bookrental.model.book;

import bookrental.model.account.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookRentals {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    private Book book;
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = ("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime dateOfRental;

    public BookRentals(Book book, User user) {
        this.book = book;
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

I set time like this:

```
private BookRentals prepareBookToRent(int userID, Book book) {
        BookRentals bookRentals = new BookRentals(book, new User(userID));
        bookRentals.setDateOfRental(LocalDateTime.now());
        return bookRentals;
    }
```

I added dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

And my JSON, looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "book": {
            "author": "Henryk Sienkiewicz",
            "category": "powieść historyczna",
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Krzyżacy"
        },
        "class": "bookrental.model.book.BookRentals",
        "dateOfRental": {
            "class": "java.time.LocalDateTime",
            "dayOfMonth": 19,
            "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
            "dayOfYear": 353,
            "hour": 0,
            "minute": 13,
            "month": "DECEMBER",
            "monthValue": 12,
            "nano": 758649300,
            "second": 8,
            "year": 2018
        },
        "id": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "piotri",
            "password": "123"
        }
    }
]
```

What else should I do?

I didn't try solutions with classes, because I dont know, where I should put them in what package.
// **EDIT**
After Erik's advice, pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.book.rental.piotrek</groupId>
<artifactId>BookRental</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Upgrading didn't work.
JSON:

```
[
    {
        "book": {
            "author": "Henryk Sienkiewicz",
            "category": "powieść historyczna",
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Krzyżacy"
        },
        "dateOfRental": {
            "dayOfMonth": 19,
            "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
            "dayOfYear": 353,
            "hour": 11,
            "minute": 22,
            "month": "DECEMBER",
            "monthValue": 12,
            "nano": 884499000,
            "second": 17,
            "year": 2018
        },
        "id": 7,
        "user": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "admin",
            "password": "123"
        }
    }
]
```

BookRentals:

```
package bookrental.model.book;

import bookrental.model.account.User;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookRentals {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    private Book book;
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    private LocalDateTime dateOfRental;

    public BookRentals(Book book, User user) {
        this.book = book;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**//EDIT2**

Hey. Accidently I found the cause of problem. I've got class that is responsible for finding exact rantals for exact user. When I go to `/books/rentals/{userID}` Im getting properly foramtted date. As you can see method return `List<BookRentals>`. In `BookRentalsService` I return ResponseEntity and I think because of that it looks like this. Do you know how to resolve it?

```
    package bookrental.service.account;

    import bookrental.model.book.BookRentals;
    import bookrental.repository.book.BookRentalsRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class UserRentalsService {

        private final BookRentalsRepository bookRentalsRepository;

        @Autowired
        public UserRentalsService(BookRentalsRepository bookRentalsRepository) {
            this.bookRentalsRepository = bookRentalsRepository;
        }

        public List<BookRentals> findUserRentalsByGivenID(int userID) {
            return bookRentalsRepository.getUserRentalsByGivenID(userID);
        }
    }


package bookrental.controller.account;

import bookrental.model.book.BookRentals;
import bookrental.service.account.UserRentalsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserRentalsController {

    private final UserRentalsService userRentalsService;

    @Autowired
    public UserRentalsController(UserRentalsService userRentalsService) {
        this.userRentalsService = userRentalsService;
    }

    @GetMapping("books/rentals/{userID}")
    public List<BookRentals> findUserRentalsByGivenID(@PathVariable int userID) {
        return userRentalsService.findUserRentalsByGivenID(userID);
    }
}
```

**BookRentalsService**

```
package bookrental.service.book.rentals;

import bookrental.model.account.User;
import bookrental.model.book.Book;
import bookrental.model.book.BookRentals;
import bookrental.repository.account.UserRepository;
import bookrental.repository.book.BookRepository;
import bookrental.repository.book.BookRentalsRepository;
import flexjson.JSONSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BookRentalService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    private final BookRentalsRepository bookRentalsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BookRentalService(BookRepository bookRepository, BookRentalsRepository bookRentalsRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
        this.bookRentalsRepository = bookRentalsRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    ....

    public ResponseEntity<String> findAllRentals() {
        List<BookRentals> rentedBooks = new ArrayList<>();
        bookRentalsRepository.findAll().forEach(rentedBooks::add);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new JSONSerializer().exclude("book.class")
                .exclude("book.available")
                .exclude("dateOfReturn")
                .exclude("*.class")
                .exclude("user.amountOfCashToPay")
                .exclude("password")
                .serialize(rentedBooks), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) yet?

Comment: Try the solution with the serializer.class just put them in the same package where your `prepareBooktoRent` class is

Comment: @OleV.V. no I don't. I dont know where to put mapper.

Comment: try Tagas' solution first,just read the solution below

Comment: @KekaBron I edited my question as to update code.

Comment: Hi there! Are you using Spring Boot 1.5.x and 2.0.x at the same time? Seems you're using start-json:2.0.5, in combination with Spring Boot 1.5.9.

Comment: @ErikPragt Hi, I've updated pom.xml. I deleted version of start-json. But it did not work.

Comment: (I just checked, there is no spring-boot-starter-json for 1.x. Why did you actually go for a 1.5 version of spring boot?)

Comment: @ErikPragt here they guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628674/spring-boot-issues-serializing-java-time-localdatetime-with-jackson-to-return-is has 1.3.6 SpringBoot.

Comment: Well, how about going for the newest version (which is 2.1.1, see https://start.spring.io)

Comment: I've published my complete example here: https://github.com/bodiam/spring-boot-java8-json-time

Comment: Service layer shouldn't return ResponseEntity. It's bad design.
ResponseEntity should exists only on Controller layer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated example using Spring 2.1.1:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@SpringBootApplication
class PipilamApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PipilamApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public Demo demo() {
        return new Demo("pipilam",LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Demo {
    String name;
    LocalDateTime dateTime;
}
```

Connecting to http://localhost:8080/demo gives the following output:

```
{"name":"pipilam","dateTime":"2018-12-19T20:16:12.780268"}
```

No configuration nor annotations needed. Consider [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot) deprecated. This is the pom.xml I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>pipilam</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pipilam</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You can find the project in Github here: https://github.com/bodiam/spring-boot-java8-json-time

Comment: With Spring data, you can define your own methods. Please make a new question for that, and I understand the frustration, but it might be better to keep that to yourself instead of writing it on SO.

Comment: Well... I made everything as you (or I overlooked something) and it does not work. I updated my question. Could you check it out?

Comment: Did you try my github project? I have no idea what your current code looks like.

Comment: Well, your answer here mostly cover with github project. Here is my current code: https://github.com/must1/BookRental

Comment: I tried different combination... Really I dont know what is going on. Could you help, please?

Comment: Well, I need ResponseEntity so I can not change as to your example exactly. My github is edited then you can check current code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what did the trick for me, running Spring Boot 3.0.2:

I just added the annotation

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING)
```

to the regarding field inside my dto, resulting in

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING)
private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

This way the result went from

```
"timestamp": [
    2023,
    2,
    3,
    12,
    29,
    20,
    584451000
],
```

to the wanted ISO format

```
"timestamp": "2023-02-03T12:29:20.584451",
```

The reason this happens is because the default value for the json format is `Shape.ANY` and the [now isolated `ObjectMapper`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#actuator-json) parses single integers to an array. The annotation forces the `ObjectMapper` to actually parse the value as a String.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need the `@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)` and `@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)`?

I had the exact same problem, also using the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency. Switching to [spring-boot-starter-json](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-json/pom.xml) solved the issue for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, it was the one of solutionts from the link with annotations:D I removed annotations and switched dependecy. Still does not work :(

Comment: Hmm, what if you also remove `@JsonFormat(pattern = ("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))`? Just wondering if that changes something...

Answer (score 0):

In your code remove the annotation `@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)` and modify your annotation 
`@JsonFormat(pattern = ("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))` to this:
 `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))`
 See [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization) for more details