# java.util.Date - Test Conversion US <-> UK

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, date-conversion

I have this test code below.

Lines /// 1 /// and /// 2 /// are alternatives.

If I use line /// 2 /// the output looks buggy, seems it does not account for the fact that US Boston and UK London do not differ by 5 hours during the whole year. If I use line /// 1 /// it looks OK, seems it accounts for that fact. Why so? Where is the conceptual difference? Why is shifting both dates by 1 day like this (I mean as in /// 2 ///) incorrect?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZoneExample02 {

    // private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar bostonTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

        Calendar londonTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
        londonTime.setTimeInMillis(bostonTime.getTimeInMillis());

        bostonTime.getTime();
        londonTime.getTime();

        for (int i=0; i>=-500; i--){
            bostonTime.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            // londonTime.setTimeInMillis(bostonTime.getTimeInMillis()); /// 1 ///
            londonTime.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); /// 2 ///

            bostonTime.getTime();
            londonTime.getTime();

            System.out.printf("Boston time: %s", getString(bostonTime));
            System.out.print(" /// ");
            System.out.printf("London time: %s\n", getString(londonTime));
        }
    }


    private static String getString(Calendar c){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", c.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
        sb.append(".");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

OUTPUT 1:

Boston time: 2013-10-30 18:51:12. /// London time: 2013-10-30 22:51:12.
Boston time: 2013-10-29 18:51:12. /// London time: 2013-10-29 22:51:12.
Boston time: 2013-10-28 18:51:12. /// London time: 2013-10-28 22:51:12.
Boston time: 2013-10-27 18:51:12. /// London time: 2013-10-27 22:51:12.
Boston time: 2013-10-26 18:51:12. /// London time: 2013-10-26 23:51:12.
Boston time: 2013-10-25 18:51:12. /// London time: 2013-10-25 23:51:12.
Boston time: 2013-10-24 18:51:12. /// London time: 2013-10-24 23:51:12.

OUTPUT 2:

Boston time: 2013-10-30 18:50:53. /// London time: 2013-10-30 23:50:53.
Boston time: 2013-10-29 18:50:53. /// London time: 2013-10-29 23:50:53.
Boston time: 2013-10-28 18:50:53. /// London time: 2013-10-28 23:50:53.
Boston time: 2013-10-27 18:50:53. /// London time: 2013-10-27 23:50:53.
Boston time: 2013-10-26 18:50:53. /// London time: 2013-10-26 23:50:53.
Boston time: 2013-10-25 18:50:53. /// London time: 2013-10-25 23:50:53.
Boston time: 2013-10-24 18:50:53. /// London time: 2013-10-24 23:50:53.

Comment: Tangent: it is [highly recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589870/should-i-use-java-date-and-time-classes-or-go-with-a-3rd-party-library-like-joda) to use the JodaTime library rather than java.util.Date.

Comment: What do you think is wrong?  What is the output that you don't expect?  I see nothing wrong with this code (apart from the occasional superfluous bits, of course).

Comment: Yes, I've heard that a few times here on SO. But first wanted to play with Java's built-in capabilities.

Comment: /// 2 /// is wrong because it shows that Boston and London always have 5 hours difference which is not true for the whole year (I believe so). E.g. on 2013-10-30 the difference was just 4 hours (as London and Boston change winter/summer on different days). /// 1 /// is OK with that respect.

Comment: On the other hand, there's little point in using JodaTime for something that works OK in the JDK classes.  Not understanding how dates and times work isn't a good reason for using a whole new library, because you'll still not understand how they work.

Comment: What do you mean "/// 2 /// is wrong"?  What output are you getting that you don't expect?

Comment: Oops, I think I realized the conceptual difference. When shifting by 1 day it does not mean I am shifting by 24 hours (as when clock changes happen those days may have 23/25 hours). Well, still not sure what happens here. Would appreciate any clear explanation as it's too late at my location now :) Yeah, probably it's this.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone, still would appreciate a good academic/expert answer :)

Comment: FYI, to clarify, London time [changed](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=136&year=2013) with Daylight Saving Time (DST) ending on 2013-10-27 when 2 AM became 1 AM (again).

Comment: @peter.petrov Since you now understand the issue completely, why don't you have a go at writing your own "good academic answer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## London DST

London time changed with [Daylight Saving Time (DST) ending](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=136&year=2013) on 2013-10-27 when 2 AM became 1 AM (again).

## Features, Not Bugs

The [documentation for java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) in its discussion at top explains that `unlike set(), add() forces an immediate recomputation of the calendar's milliseconds and all fields.`

Furthermore, the [documentation for java.util.GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) on the `add` method notes that smaller units of time are **not adjusted**. The doc specifically notes that `HOUR` is a smaller field that `DAY_OF_MONTH`, so it is not adjusted. Meaning that you started with an hour of 23 so you'll end up with an hour of 23, with milliseconds-since-[epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) recomputed as needed.

The behaviors you see for the `set` and `add` methods are both correct. **Features, not bugs.**

## Indirect Answer

The bundled [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), java.util.Calendar, and java.text.SimpleDateFormat are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and tricky. They have flaws in both design and implementation.

I understand your interest in "to play with Java's built-in capabilities". While that interest is generally laudable, in this specific corner of Java, it is a waste of time. *Even Sun and Oracle have given up* on these classes. [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) brings a whole new java.time.* package, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), and supplanting the old bundled classes.

If you cannot yet move to Java 8, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Joda-Time works in multiple versions of Java, and continues to work in Java 8 as it is actively maintained.

### Example Code

Some example code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 to get you going.

**Some Notes…**

A Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) actually knows its own time zone. In contrast, a java.util.Date has no time zone yet its `toString` method applies the JVM's default time zone which creates no end of confusion.

Note in this example that `dateTime_Boston` and `dateTime_London` have the same number of milliseconds-since-epoch.

Joda-Time by default uses standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for string output, like this `2014-02-13T10:32:28.131+05:30`.

The `+` or `-` at the end marks a time zone offset from UTC/GMT. Do *not* read this as an operand in a formula. Read this as a label saying, for example, "India has a time zone offset of +05:30, so the date-time displayed is five and a half hours ahead of UTC/GMT".

- PLUS SIGN ("+") means *ahead of UTC/GMT*.
- HYPHEN-MINUS ("-") means *behind UTC/GMT*.

The `Z` at the end is pronounced "Zulu" and is shorthand for `+00:00`. That means UTC/GMT time zone, that is, no time zone offset.

```java
// Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone_Boston = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTimeZone timeZone_London = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" );

DateTime dateTime_Boston = new DateTime( 2013, 10, 27, 22, 51, 12, timeZone_Boston );
DateTime dateTime_London = dateTime_Boston.toDateTime( timeZone_London ); 
DateTime earlier_London = dateTime_London.minusDays( 2 ); // Use '2' to get us before DST change.
DateTime earlier_UtcGmt = earlier_London.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime_Boston " + dateTime_Boston );
System.out.println( "dateTime_London " + dateTime_London );
System.out.println( "earlier_London " + earlier_London );
System.out.println( "earlier_UtcGmt " + earlier_UtcGmt );
```

When run…

```
dateTime_Boston 2013-10-27T22:51:12.000-04:00
dateTime_London 2013-10-28T02:51:12.000Z
earlier_London 2013-10-26T02:51:12.000+01:00
earlier_UtcGmt 2013-10-26T01:51:12.000Z
```

Comment: Thank you. Your examples are using the Joda time library, right? I am pretty sure but just making sure.

Comment: @peter.petrov Yep, Joda-Time 2.3, that's what it says under "Example Code" heading.